# useStore is not a function error from Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I tried to find a solution to

> (0 , pinia__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useStore) is not a function

but found nothing. What am I doing wrong?

This is my store.js code

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const myStore = defineStore("myStore", {
  state: () => ({
    count: 0,
    message: "Hello, Pinia!",
  }),
  actions: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    },
    updateMessage(newMessage) {
      this.message = newMessage;
    },
  },
});
```

And this is my App.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Count: {{ store.count }}</p>
    <button @click="store.increment">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "pinia";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore("myStore");

    return {
      store,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: make sure you install the npm package: npm install pinia

Comment: I already did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useStore` is not a function from Pinia.  This should be removed:

```js
import { useStore } from "pinia";
```

When the [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Using-the-store) mention creating a useStore function, that function is whatever you export from your store.js code. In your case it's `myStore`, though by convention it should be `useMyStore`

```js
export const useMyStore = defineStore("myStore", { ... })
```

Then you import where needed

```js
import { useMyStore } from 'store.js'

const store = useMyStore()
```